# Error rate calculation in UART

Tags: stm32, uart

I am analyzing the error rate in UART communication. Can anyone tell me how to measure the **bit error rate** in **UART** communication?
Is this possible to measure the error rate by Pico-Scope or by using Matlab? If possible what is the method to do that?

in my project, I have established UART communication, which is working fine. Now I want to use the Bit error model (https://www.academia.edu/21336422/Bit_error_models) to analyze the error rate in communication. What is the physical method to calculate the error (which bits are falling between the threshold of '0' and '1' )

Comment: What errors are detectable in your UART configuration?  Framing errors, parity errors, errors of application-layer checksums ?

Comment: Do you mean bit error rate or simply the error in baud rate?

Comment: To calculate a *theoretical* rate or to count the errors from the actual communication session?

Comment: I want  to calculate the error rate in an actual communication session

Comment: The UART hardware can just detect framing errors. This isn't the same thing as bit error rate - it's rather a byte error rate at best. To detect bit errors you would need a CRC on the higher layer, and it's only reliable for detecting single bit errors. Multi-bit/burst errors in the payload are harder to catch by CRC. You can also use parity but that's 1960s stone age stuff and very prone to miss most errors.

Answer (score 2):

You want to measure the bit error rate in a TxUART-to-RxUART communication path.

I'll assume here that the TxUART and RxUART are within MCUs.

There is plenty of professional equipment and documentation of the subject on the internet. I'll also assume that you want to produce your own instead.

You can drive a known bit pattern out of the TxUART. Then the RxUART can can receive comms and check against that known bit pattern, counting any bit differences. The total number of bits received and the number of incorrect bits received give you a bit error rate.

The known pattern must be:

- Predictable, so that the RxUART MCU can generate the same bit data as the TxUART MCU generated.
- Troublesome, so that it encourages bit errors. High speed near/at the link limit, a difficult pattern (not sending all '0's, as an extreme example)
- Simple to generate, so the MCUs can keep up with the rate of consumption for the link speed
- Easy for the RxUART MCU to synchronise to and short enough to re-lock onto quickly, if bit errors cause a loss of synchronisation (RxUART MCU loses its place in the sequence)

For test data, you could just use an incrementing byte pattern. That starts off mostly zeroes and ends up mostly ones, with the only abrupt change occurring at 0xFF->0x00. But it would be an easy sequence for your RxUART MCU to synchronise itself to.

Or you could use a Linear Feedback Shift Register (LFSR) to generate the sequence. LFSRs are a subject in themselves and there's plenty of info on the internet explaining them.

You would want to a pattern that repeats quickly enough for the receiver to lock onto in an acceptable time. So a pattern that repeats every 1 sec, for example, so your receiver can find a known place in the pattern quickly and lock on again if bit errors cause it to lose synchronisation. Some patterns are easier to lock onto than others, e.g. incrementing bytes are easy, random data from a table in both devices is hard and needs table searches.

Answer (score 0):

Measure the bit error rate? First few ways to do this some are more complicated than others the most simplest way is to just send a known message if you are using a 16-bit packet then send something like 55h or AAh and then check to see if you get something different. Then take the number of errors and divide sit by the number of packets you sent.

Another way to turn parity on and check to see how many CRC misses you have.